# Exclude postfix log from syslog / journald

Tags: logging, postfix, systemd

Is it possible to configure journalctl to exclude certain sources, like postfix, from the system log? Or can I exclude postfix messages from the system log by specifying another syslog facility (without breaking all other logging)?

Postfix messages are logged to `/var/log/maillog` *as well as* `/var/log/mail.log` for some reason on my server (I assume that's due to Plesk). Also keeping them in the system log is a level of redundancy I don't need.

I'd like to keep the postfix log in `/var/log/maillog` without having thousands of messages a day in the "global" system log (shown by `journalctl`).

The target system runs Ubuntu 16.04.5 w/ systemd init. As I read it, journalctl can't filter/ignore input, but postfix can be configured for other `syslog facilities`. Could a standalone `rsyslogd` be installed and run alongside `systemd-journald`?

Comment: `rsyslogd` can be installed alongside `journald`.